# RealmSearchAdapter not recylcing the view

Tags: android, realm, android-adapter, android-recyclerview

I have a gridview with items that I can increase or diminish its values, what is happening is when I change the value of the item and scroll down the screen
and scroll back the change that I made is gone, and if I scroll down and up a couple times I can see the change that I made again, what am I missing here?

```
public class SearchItemViewAdapter extends RealmSearchAdapter<Itens, SearchItemViewAdapter.ViewHolder> implements RealmChangeListener {

    public SparseBooleanArray mSparseBooleanArray;

    public SearchItemViewAdapter(Activity context, Realm realm, String filterColumnName) {
        super(context, realm, filterColumnName);
        mSparseBooleanArray = new SparseBooleanArray();

    }

    @Override
    public void onChange() {
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public RealmList<Itens> getCheckedItems() {
        RealmList<Itens> mTempArry = new RealmList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < realmResults.size(); i++) {
            if (mSparseBooleanArray.get(i)) {
                mTempArry.add(realmResults.get(i));
            }
        }


        return mTempArry;
    }


    public class ViewHolder extends RealmSearchViewHolder {

        public SearchItemView itemView;

        public ViewHolder(FrameLayout container, TextView footerTextView) {
            super(container, footerTextView);
        }

        public ViewHolder(SearchItemView itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.itemView = itemView;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateRealmViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(new SearchItemView(viewGroup.getContext()));
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindRealmViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        final Itens item = realmResults.get(position);
        viewHolder.itemView.bind(item);

        viewHolder.itemView.check.setTag(position);

        viewHolder.itemView.check.setChecked(mSparseBooleanArray.get(position));
        viewHolder.itemView.check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(mCheckedChangeListener);

    }

    CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener mCheckedChangeListener = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            mSparseBooleanArray.put((Integer) buttonView.getTag(), isChecked);
        }
    };

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateFooterViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.footer_view, viewGroup, false);
        return new ViewHolder(
                (FrameLayout) v,
                (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.footer_text_view));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindFooterViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        super.onBindFooterViewHolder(holder, position);
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                    }
                }
        );


    }


}
```

SearchItemView

```
 public class SearchItemView extends RelativeLayout {

       @Bind(R.id.codigo)
        TextView codigo;

        @Bind(R.id.nomeproduto)
        TextView nome;

        @Bind(R.id.preco)
        TextView preco;

        @Bind(R.id.valor)
        TextView itemq;

        @Bind(R.id.more)
        ImageView more;

        @Bind(R.id.less)
        ImageView less;

        @Bind(R.id.check)
        CheckBox check;


        final int nStart = 0;
        final int nEnd = 10000000;

        public SearchItemView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            init(context);
        }

        private void init(Context context) {
            inflate(context, R.layout.add_itens_adapter, this);
            ButterKnife.bind(this);
        }

        public void bind(Itens item) {
            nome.setText(item.getNome());
            codigo.setText(item.getCodigo());
            preco.setText(item.getPreco());




            more.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String getString = String.valueOf(itemq.getText());
                    int curent = Integer.parseInt(getString);
                    if (v == more) {
                        if (curent < nEnd) {
                            curent++;
                            itemq.setText(String.valueOf(curent));
                        }
                    }


                }
            });

            less.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String getString = String.valueOf(itemq.getText());
                    int curent = Integer.parseInt(getString);
                    if (v == less) {
                        if (curent > nStart) {
                            curent--;
                            itemq.setText(String.valueOf(curent));
                        }
                    }
                }
            });


        }
    }
```

Comment: `onCreateRealmViewHolder` seems to be a custom method. Probably that is being called in the wrong place? Have you looked at his RecyclerView example here: https://github.com/realm/realm-android-adapters/tree/master/example/src/main/java/io/realm/examples/adapters/ui/recyclerview Perhaps that can give you some hints to what is wrong in your code

Comment: If I were U, I`d add in my model RealmObject (Itens for you) field "isChecked" and call in onBind method viewHolder.itemView.check.setChecked(item.isChecked)

and when user tap on item -> save in realm item.isChecked = !item.isChecked

Comment: @ChristianMelchior I followed this tutorial https://realm.io/news/android-search-text-view/